# How many generators do a 4-strands braid group have?

Tags: group-theory, braid-groups

I know that this might be a trivial question, but, I'm asking that because source on the topic tend to give different presentations.
Maybe  it's just me not noticing the difference, but I'd like to point it out bacuase I think it can be helpful to avoid confusion for someone who is approaching braid groups. The problem lies in what is considered generators of abraid group, in particular a 4-strands to be specific. Are inverses of the 3 "standard" braids included in the set of generators?($\displaystyle \sigma 1$, $\displaystyle \sigma 2$, $\displaystyle \sigma 3$).

[image]

For example [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group) talks about 3 generators while a bunch of other sources include the inverses ($\displaystyle \sigma 1^{-1}$, $\displaystyle \sigma 2^{-1}$, $\displaystyle \sigma 3^{-1}$) in the set of generators.
My intuition tells me to include them too, but I'm afraid I'm missing ssomething.

Comment: Inverses are not needed as they appear automatically: A subset $S$ of a group $G$ generates $G$, so $G=\langle S\rangle$, if no proper subgroup of $G$ contains the set $S$. The group $\langle S\rangle$ may be viewed as the product of all elements of $S$ *and their inverses*. [For finite groups, $\langle S\rangle$ may be views as the product of all elements of $S$.] For example, $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 1\rangle$ even though $-3$ cannot be written as a sum of $1$s.

Comment: What do you mean you "want to show that there is always confusion"?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I editeted that part because it was misleading about what I meant! :). I just wanted to say that it's easy to find different presentations.

Comment: @user1729 I didn't get what you mean, maybe it's too advanced for me.

Comment: Its not too advanced, don't worry :-) First ask yourself the following question: does $1$ generate $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @user1729 Well, -3 cannot be written as sum of 1s....

Comment: $-3$ cannot be written as the sum of $1$s, but *that's not the definition of "generates"*. Which is my point. So: what is the smallest subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contains the number $1$? [This is the *correct* definition.]

Comment: ok ({1})...I went on wikipedia page and this is where the confusion lies :"a generating set of a group is a subset such that every element of the group can be expressed as the combination (under the group operation) of finitely many elements of the subset and their inverses." Inverses aren't included in the set of generators, according to definition. if you would like to explain better what does it mean that "The group ⟨S⟩ may be viewed as the product of all elements of S and their inverses." Id'd like to accept your as an answe :)

Comment: I've written up an answer. You are misunderstanding the wiki quote. "...and their inverses" is implying that the inverses of $S$ are *not* necessarily in $S$.

Comment: @user1729 Yes I was saying that often i ndiffernt sources inverses are included, this why I believed them to be in the set of generators, but the formal definition don't need them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Definition.** Let $S\subset G$. Then the *subgroup generated by $S$*, written $\langle S\rangle$, is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. Formally: $\langle S\rangle:=\displaystyle\bigcap_{S\subset H,\\ H\leq G}H$.

Then a *generating set of $G$* is a subset $S$ of $G$ where $\langle S\rangle=G$. For example, $\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{Z}$.

There is nothing in this definition about "products of elements". However, it turns out that the following holds:

> A set $S$ generates $G$ if and only if every element $g\in G$ can be written as a product of elements from $S\cup S^{-1}$ (where $S^{-1}:=\{s^{-1}\mid s\in S\}$ is the set of inverses of elements of $S$).

The phrase from Wikipedia "The group $\langle S\rangle$ may be viewed as the product of all elements of $S$ and their inverses" is implying that the inverses of $S$ are *not* necessarily in $S$! For example, every integer can be written as a sum of $1$s and of $-1$s, so $\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{Z}$. To be clear: *there is no assumption that $S=S^{-1}$*.

Lets end on an exercise, which basically says you can ignore this subtlety for finite groups:

> **Exercise.** Prove that set $S$ generates $G$ if and only if every element $g\in G$ can be written as a product of elements from $S$.